# Linq compare enum to byte

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LInq statement:

```
public class TestClass<T> : Form where T: struct, IConvertible
{
    private class MyObject
    {
        public byte Number {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
    }

    private IReadonlyDictionary<string, T> myListA;
    private List<MyObject> myListB;

    public void Convert()
    {
        var query = (from a in myListA
                     join b in MyListB
                     on a.Value equals b.Number
                     select new
                         {
                             b.Name
                         }).ToList();
    }
}
```

How to I compare `a.Value` with `b.Number`?

Comment: Is `a.Value` a string?  Your dictionary doesn't type its `Value` property.  It's the dictionary value?

Comment: @ryanyuyu a.Value is of type T (which is an enum)

Comment: A short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem would make this question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: cast enum value to byte explizitly using `(byte)`

Comment: @Jehof Doesn't work. Error is: `Cannot convert type 'T' to 'byte'`

Comment: It's a compilation error.

Comment: interface _IConvertible_ have method [IConvertible.ToByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.tobyte(v=vs.110).aspx) for converting

Comment: Why can you not either make the object contain the enum value or the dictionary hold byte values?

Comment: Add an example of type T. You said earlier  "a.Value is of type T (which is an enum) " but your restriction is "where T: struct, IConvertible". I dont know which is which anymore

Comment: The restriction `where T: struct, IConvertible` is to restrict `T` as an enum.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: That doesn't restrict it to an enum though. `DateTime` satisfies that, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Call `ToByte`

```
a.Value.ToByte(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) == b.Number
```

or try

```
Convert.ToByte(a.Value) == b.Number
```